# Updating Multiple row in php to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Below is my code to update multiple rows to mysql database from php Everything works fine but all of a sudden it show "NO DATABASE SELECTED". And i am unable to see the any data on the page. Whats wrong in my code anyway??

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>CS SEM-1 SUB-1</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/style-table.js"></script>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function()
    {
        if($(this).val() == 0) $(this).val('');
    });
});
</script>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function t1()
{
    {
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function()
    {
        if($(this).val() == '') $(this).val('0');
    });
}

    }
</script>


<link href="css/css-table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="cs1_s1" align="center">
    <?php
    include"connections\connect.php";
    if ( isset( $_POST["submit1"] ) ) {

        foreach( $_POST["id"] AS $id ) {
            $may_tc_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["may_tc_s1"][$id] );
            $may_ac_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["may_ac_s1"][$id] );
            $jun_tc_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["jun_tc_s1"][$id] );
            $jun_ac_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["jun_ac_s1"][$id] );
            $jul_tc_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["jul_tc_s1"][$id] );
            $jul_ac_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["jul_ac_s1"][$id] );
            $aug_tc_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["aug_tc_s1"][$id] );
            $aug_ac_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["aug_ac_s1"][$id] );
            $sep_tc_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["sep_tc_s1"][$id] );
            $sep_ac_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["sep_ac_s1"][$id] );
            $oct_tc_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["oct_tc_s1"][$id] );
            $oct_ac_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["oct_ac_s1"][$id] );
            $nov_tc_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["nov_tc_s1"][$id] );
            $nov_ac_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["nov_ac_s1"][$id] );
            $s1_t1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["s1_t1"][$id] );
            $s1_t2 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["s1_t2"][$id] );
            $s1_t3 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["s1_t3"][$id] );

            $update = " UPDATE `attendence` SET 
            `may_tc_s1` = '$may_tc_s1',
            `may_ac_s1` = '$may_ac_s1',
            `jun_tc_s1` = '$jun_tc_s1',
            `jun_ac_s1` = '$jun_ac_s1',
            `jul_tc_s1` = '$jul_tc_s1',
            `jul_ac_s1` = '$jul_ac_s1',
            `aug_tc_s1` = '$aug_tc_s1',
            `aug_ac_s1` = '$aug_ac_s1',
            `sep_tc_s1` = '$sep_tc_s1',
            `sep_ac_s1` = '$sep_ac_s1',
            `oct_tc_s1` = '$oct_tc_s1',
            `oct_ac_s1` = '$oct_ac_s1',
            `nov_tc_s1` = '$nov_tc_s1',
            `nov_ac_s1` = '$nov_ac_s1',
            `s1_t1` = '$s1_t1',
            `s1_t2` = '$s1_t2',
            `s1_t3` = '$s1_t3'
             WHERE `idatten` =$id LIMIT 1 ; ";
            mysql_query( $update ) or die( mysql_error() );
        }
    }
$sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM attendence WHERE branch = 'cs' AND attendence.semester=1 ORDER BY attendence.rollno")or die(mysql_error());

    //check if the starting row variable was passed in the URL or not
if (!isset($_GET['startrow']) or !is_numeric($_GET['startrow'])) {
  //we give the value of the starting row to 0 because nothing was found in URL
  $startrow = 0;
  //otherwise we take the value from the URL
} else {
  $startrow = (int)$_GET['startrow'];
  }
//this part goes after the checking of the $_GET var
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM attendence WHERE branch = 'cs' AND attendence.semester=1 ORDER BY attendence.rollno LIMIT $startrow, 15")or
die(mysql_error());
    if ( mysql_num_rows( $sql ) > 0 ) {

        echo'<form id="form_s1" method="post">';
        echo' <table border="0" align="center">';
        echo' <tr>';
        echo' <th><div align="center">ID</div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center">Student Name</div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center">Roll No</div></th>';
        echo' <th colspan="2"><div align="center">May</div></th>';
        echo' <th colspan="2"><div align="center">Jun</div></th>';
        echo' <th colspan="2"><div align="center">Jul</div></th>';
        echo' <th colspan="2"><div align="center">Aug</div></th>';
        echo' <th colspan="2"><div align="center">Sep</div></th>';
        echo' <th colspan="2"><div align="center">Oct</div></th>';
        echo' <th colspan="2"><div align="center">Nov</div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center">T1</div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center">T2</div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center">T3</div></th>';
        echo' </tr>';
        echo' <tr>';
        echo' <th><div align="center"></div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center"></div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center"></div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center">TC</div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center">AC</div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center">TC</div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center">AC</div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center">TC</div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center">AC</div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center">TC</div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center">AC</div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center">TC</div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center">AC</div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center">TC</div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center">AC</div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center">TC</div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center">AC</div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center"></div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center"></div></th>';
        echo' <th><div align="center"></div></th>';
        echo' </tr>';
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $sql ) ) {
        echo' <tr>';
        echo' <td>'.$row["idatten"] . '</td>';
        echo' <td>'.$row["username"] . '</td>';
        echo' <td>'.$row["rollno"] .'</td>';
        echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="may_tc_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["may_tc_s1"] . '"></td>';
        echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="may_ac_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["may_ac_s1"] . '"></td>';
        echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="jun_tc_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["jun_tc_s1"] . '"></td>';
        echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="jun_ac_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["jun_ac_s1"] . '"></td>';
        echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="jul_tc_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["jul_tc_s1"] . '"></td>';
        echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="jul_ac_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["jul_ac_s1"] . '"></td>';
        echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="aug_tc_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["aug_tc_s1"] . '"></td>';
        echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="aug_ac_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["aug_ac_s1"] . '"></td>';
        echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="sep_tc_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["sep_tc_s1"] . '"></td>';
        echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="sep_ac_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["sep_ac_s1"] . '"></td>';
        echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="oct_tc_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["oct_tc_s1"] . '"></td>';
        echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="oct_ac_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["oct_ac_s1"] . '"></td>';
        echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="nov_tc_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["nov_tc_s1"] . '"></td>';
        echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="nov_ac_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["nov_ac_s1"] . '"></td>';    
        echo' <td><input size="4" type="text" name="s1_t1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["s1_t1"] . '"></td>';
        echo' <td><input size="4" type="text" name="s1_t2[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["s1_t2"] . '"></td>';
        echo' <td><input size="4" type="text" name="s1_t3[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["s1_t3"] . '"></td>';
        echo' <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="' . $row["idatten"] . '">';
        echo' </tr>';
        echo' <tr>';
        }}
        $prev = $startrow - 15;
        //only print a "Previous" link if a "Next" was clicked
        if ($prev >= 0)
        echo'<td><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.$prev.'"><img src="images/pre.gif" width="84" height="41" alt="pre" /></a></td>';
        echo'<td colspan="20"><div align="center">  <input type="submit" onblur="t1()" name="submit1" value="Update Record"></div></td>';
        //now this is the link..
        $count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM attendence WHERE branch = 'cs' AND attendence.semester=1 ");
        $count = mysql_fetch_object($count);
        $count = $count->total;
        if( $count > $startrow+15)
        echo'<td><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.($startrow+15).'"><img src="images/next.gif" width="77" height="37" alt="next" /></a></td>';  
        echo' </tr>';
        echo' </table>';
        echo '</form>';
        ?>
<!-- End of cs1_s1 ---></div>


</body>
</html>
<!-- End of cs1_s1 ---></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified a database!
Use `mysql_select_db($dbname)` before mysql_query!

Which world are you living??... Still use mysql??

I highly recommend you to use `mysqli` instead of `mysql`!

Comment: include"connections\connect.php"; here it is on line 37 have used

Comment: Then prove it, share connect.php!...and how do you know about the error??.. did you use mysql_error?